# Karate report export as artifact in github actions workflow

Tags: github-actions, karate

I have the following workflow yml file in my github actions for Karate tests and I am trying to get the artifact (Karate test report and log file) irrespective of the test results but this particular job is ignored/skipped in the workflow.

```
name: ci-mvn-build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 0 * * 1-5'
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: git checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: set up jdk 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: adopt
          java-version: 11
      - name: cache maven 
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.m2/repository
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-maven-
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Starting the API testing!
      - name: test execution
        run: mvn --batch-mode clean test -DCLIENT_ID=${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }} -DM_SCOPE=${{ secrets.M_SCOPE }} -DMG_SCOPE=${{ secrets.MG_SCOPE }} -DCLIENT_SECRET=${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }} -DTENANT=${{ secrets.TENANT }}
      - name: Karate DSL Test Reports
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Test Reports
          path: | 
            ./target/karate-reports/
            ./target/karate.log
```

Workflow view:

[image]

Target Folder structure:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out that including 'always' is the trick.

**Always:**
Always returns true, even when canceled. A job or step will not run when a critical failure prevents the task from running. For example, if getting sources failed.

Example
if: ${{ always() }}

More details: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#job-status-check-functions

My final file:

```
  - name: Karate DSL Test Reports
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        if: ${{ always() }}
        with:
          name: Test Reports
          path: | 
            ./target/karate-reports/
            ./target/karate.log
```